# How can I backup connections in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

How can I backup and transfer my stored SQL Server connections from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14 to another computer (or after reinstall)? I mean connections in the "Connect to server" dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can export and then subsequently import your SQL Server connections in the way you are thinking. However, I can offer you a work around that should work for you.

If [register your servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/register-servers?view=sql-server-ver15) you should be able to export those to a file and then import them later. *Be cautious with having your passwords in that registered server export file.* I ran a test and it seems the passwords are encrypted (at least not clear text), but presumably anyone who has that file could import it an then have access to your databases. You can select to not have your passwords exported if you so choose.